# Unified UI between mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, windows, mobile, user-interface

I want to know if there is a Unified UI framework that I can use when creating a mobile application that can be used between iOS, Android and Windows Phone OS? I have never touched HTML 5 but I heard one can create complex UI so that it will look more or less same across these platforms. My idea will be to create one application, have a generic framework that can be ported easily.

EDIT:
Just found this site http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of platforms, Corona, Titanium, PhoneGap and of course HTML5 to name a few.  This does put limitations on performance and on the features that you can take advantage of.  I'm not sure if any except HTML 5 supports Windows phone, but they all support Android and iOS.

Comment: Will look into these. My only problem with HTML5 is that it isn't native (i might be wrong).

Comment: Yes, none of these are native.  I don't think there is a native solution in existence.

Comment: Just had a quick look at Corona SDK and does this mean I have to create the software in Lua? Have anyone tried this?

Comment: Yes, Lua is the language for Corona.  I have tried it, honestly I found it rather limiting after doing it native for so long.  Still, I think Corona is one of the better choices, especially for game development.